# Remove extra ;# instances from string

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a JavaScript question.

I have a string (a list of SharePoint account names) that can have a user account dropped out at any point in the string.  Example:

```
"1;#Smith, John;#47;#Doe, Jane;#13;#Bronte, Charlotte"
```

I have my code set up to drop out one of the account strings based on user selection, but that leaves a ;# separator either at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end of the string.

Dropping John Smith:

```
";#47;#Doe, Jane;#13;#Bronte, Charlotte"
```

Dropping Jane Doe:

```
"1;#Smith, John;#;#13;#Bronte, Charlotte"
```

Dropping Charlotte Bronte:

```
"1;#Smith, John;#47;#Doe, Jane;#13;#"
```

Can you provide a regex I can use to kill the remaining offending ;#?

---

Here's the removal code, where `existingUsers` is the full string, and `account` is the name to drop from the string:

```
if (existingUsers.length > account.length) {
  existingUsers.replace(account, "");
  // Clean up leftover ;# - regex
} else {
  existingUsers = "";
}
```

Comment: How are you doing the removal?

Comment: Why don't you just remove it with the name?

Comment: You need to show your code to drop names.

Comment: `existingUsers.replace(";#" + account, "");` ?

Answer (score 1):

The following expression could be used for parsing SharePoint user field value:

```
((\d+));[#]([(\w*\\)+\s]+)
```

### How to parse user field value in JavaScript

```js
function parseMultiColumnValue(fieldValue)
{
    var re = /((\d+));[#]([(\w*\\)+\s]+)/g;
    var results = [],match;
    while (match = re.exec(fieldValue)) {
       results.push({'Id' : parseInt(match[1]), 'Value': match[3]});
    }
    return results;
}  



//Tests
   
//Parse values
var values = parseMultiColumnValue('1;#user1;#4;#user2;#10;#user3');
$('div#output').append(JSON.stringify(values));

//Delete the first item 
values.splice(0, 1);
$('div#output').append(JSON.stringify(values));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var r = /(^;#|;#(?=;#)|;#$)/;
var s1 = ";#47;#Doe, Jane;#13;#Bronte, Charlotte";
var s2 = "1;#Smith, John;#;#13;#Bronte, Charlotte";
var s3 = "1;#Smith, John;#47;#Doe, Jane;#13;#";

console.log(s1.replace(r,""));
console.log(s2.replace(r,""));
console.log(s3.replace(r,""));
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

This simply matched either:

```
^;#         start of string followed by ;#
;#(?=;#)    ;# followed by another ;#
;#$         ;# followed by end of string
```

As others have suggested, it might be easier to just split the string into an array. You can `join` it back together again if you must have a string back:

```js
var s = "1;#Smith, John;#47;#Doe, Jane;#13;#Bronte, Charlotte";
var account = "1;#Smith, John";   // for example
var search = account.split(";#");
var split = s.split(";#");    
var i = split.indexOf(search[0]);  // search by number first
if (i!==-1 && split[i+1] === search[1]) {   // check the username matches too!
    split.splice(i,2);         // we remove the matching elements
    console.log(split);        // John Smith was removed
}
console.log(split.join(";#")); // If you must have a string after removing a user
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```